# How to filter a query builder with another query?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder, dql

I'm trying to do next query to the DB to get the next results:

[Expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uExub.png)

I have the table Areas, but I want to sort the results according to the responsible, it means, the responsibles with more areas at the top and the responsibles with less areas at the bottom.

**Actually I'm doing it with the next Mysql Query which works perfectly:**

```
SELECT    a.id_Area,
          a.name,
          a.responsible 
FROM      FSA_Areas a 
WHERE     enabled=TRUE 
AND       id_Plant = 1
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM   FSA_Areas a1 
          WHERE  a1.Responsible = a.Responsible 
          AND    a1.id_Plant = a.id_Plant 
          AND    Enabled='1') DESC, 
          a.responsible;
```

But now I want to do it in **Doctrine Query Builder or DQL**

I've tried this, It didt not work:

```
 $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u')
        ->from('FSABundle:FSAArea','u')
        ->orderBy($this->createQueryBuilder('u1')
                    ->select('count(u1)')
                    ->from('FSABundle:FSAArea', 'u1')
                    ->where('u1.responsible = u.responsible')
                    ->andWhere('u1.plant = u.plant')
                    ->andWhere('u1.enabled = enabled')
        ,'DESC')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $query;
```

**Any Idea about how to the same Mysql Query into DQL or Query Builder?** 

**TEST 1:**

```
 $sub = $em->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('COUNT(a.id)')
        ->from('FSABundle:FSAArea','a')
        ->where('a.responsible = u.responsible')
        ->andWhere('a.plant = u.plant')
        ->andWhere('a.enabled = :status')
        ->setParameter('status','true');

    $qb->select('u')
        ->from('FSABundle:FSAArea','u')
        ->where('u.enabled = :status')
        ->andWhere('u.plant = :idPlant')
        ->setParameter('status','enabled')
        ->setParameter('idPlant','1')
        ->orderBy($sub->getDQL(),'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: your inner query probably needs a `->getQuery()->getDQL()` (or however that function is named). Also, you might want to expand on the "it did not work" comment, because there probably was an error message, otherwise *some* query would have run, in which case you could have checked the query.

Comment: I've made many tests about how to get the expected result, also I've edited my question adding what I've tried. But it doesn´t work yet. Now with TEST 1 example I get : " Error: Expected end of string, got 'COUNT'" I would appreciate any advice @Jakumi

Comment: try `->orderBy('('.$sub->getDQL().')', 'DESC')` sub-queries almost always work better with parentheses.